# Graph line not moving with zoomable chart area

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been going through several of the d3 blocks trying to put one of my own together and I can't figure out why the graph line isn't moving with the rest of the graph.

Here's a fiddle with my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/asa1q7tx/1/

I assume the problem is that I'm not updating the line in the 'zoomed' function but I'm not sure what to do. Here's the 'zoomed' function from the fiddle:

```
function zoomed() {
  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
}
```

Comment: well i can see your fiddle working on zoom +pan dont see any issues.

Comment: If you pan around the line only updates after the transition finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update path in your zoomed function. Right now, your tick function which is called every 500ms is doing that for you, but this is not smooth.

```
function zoomed() {
  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
  path.attr('d',line);  // This line updates path
}
```

You might as well stop the animation of the path and start it over after zoom effect.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was simple but I got myself confused. Any suggestions for how to pause and restart the transition?